# Searching ChatGPT transcripts?

Tags: information-retrieval, tools, search, chatgpt

Maybe I just don't understand the functionality of the web version. Using GPT4 here.

When I do technical queries (usually TensorFlow applications) I use similar prompts until I get the understanding I need. I want to be able to retrieve chats using folders or keywords that I assign, or some other such method.

When I ask GPT I'm told web browser history or Evernote / other note-taking software is what I should use. Surely there is some sort more powerful search available?

At the moment I cut-and-paste important chats into word processor documents. This is just ridiculous when I'm paying for a service that's supposed to make information retrieval / analysis quicker and easier.

All I can find are Chrome extensions like "Superpower ChatGPT", which requires a paid subscription. I'm dubious how long these sorts of extensions will be around, and don't want to lose the effort I'll need to put into adding keywords etc if the extension stops being developed.

Answer (score 1):

Had asked on Reddit too. Didn't expect an answer, but [Easy ChatGPT folders](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/chatgpt-easy-folders-chat/gdocioajfidpnaejbgmbnkflgmppibfe) was suggested. It has full chat history search and nested folders. Also bulk delete.
Rating of 4.5 from 21 reviews, and 2000 users.
So I'll be trying it out. Will report back here if it doesn't work for me.
Also a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x9VbOAm0tY)

Comment: Started using it and there is a paid version upgrade, where most of the useful features are. Only 10 folders in the free version. And the paid version is expensive by my standards. So I can't recommend it over the other options out there.